# React Input component unit test value always undefined

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, enzyme

I have input component I want write unit test for it, I tried but I am always getting input value as an undefined below is the code Thanks.

```
import React from 'react'
import chai, {expect} from 'chai';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
import Input from './Input';

describe('Input Component', () => {
   let wrapper
    beforeEach( ()=>{
        let props = {
            placeholder:"name",
            name:"name",
            value:"myName",
            change:() =>{},
            classes:"input"
        }
        wrapper = mount(<Input defaultValue="myName"  />);
        //wrapper = mount(<Input {...props}  />);
        console.log(wrapper.find('input').value) // always getting undefined
    })
    it('Input default value should be myName', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('input').value).to.be.equal("myName");
  })
});
```

Comment: please add your code from `./Input` component. did you set the input value to `this.props.defaultValue` in `render()` or componentDidMount ?

Comment: Please share your input compinent code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get the attribute of the element you need to use `.prop()`

```
import React from "react";
import chai, { expect } from "chai";
import { shallow, mount } from "enzyme";
import { configure } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { Input } from "./index.js";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("Input Component", () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    let props = {
      placeholder: "name",
      name: "name",
      value: "myName",
      change: () => {},
      classes: "input"
    };
    //wrapper = mount(<Input defaultValue="myName" />);
    wrapper = mount(<Input {...props} />);
    console.log(wrapper.debug());
    console.log(wrapper.find(".input")); // always getting undefined
  });
  it("Input default value should be myName", () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(".input").prop('value')).to.be.equal("myName");
  });
});
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/7j43jry2x)

Comment: if you dont mine can you give me an example to input change listener test case

Comment: @NareshManthena, I haven't worked with chai, can't provide you an example using chai